# React Immutable Generic Arrow to update a nested state of controlled fields

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for the best approach to update one or more fields, using a generic function based on event.target.name without mutating the state.

Example:

```
  onInputChange = event => {
    const newEvent = this.state.event
    newEvent[event.target.name] = event.target.value
    this.setState({
      event: newEvent
    })
  }
```

The function above works and is doing the job. However it is mutating the state right before the setState method, as newEvent is a reference.

Using the spread operator to copy the state does not work as expected. 
What I'm missing ?

**See the full Code and more in depth analysis below.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class EventForm extends Component {
  state = {
    event: {
      title: '',
      venue: ''
    }
  }

  onFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    //..
  }

  onInputChange = event => {
    const newEvent = this.state.event
    newEvent[event.target.name] = event.target.value
    this.setState({
      event: newEvent
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { event } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          Title: {this.state.event.title}
          <br />
          Venue: {this.state.event.venue}
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <label>Event Title</label>
          <input
            placeholder="title"
            name="title"
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
            value={event.title}
          />
          <label>Venue</label>
          <input
            name="venue"
            placeholder="Event Venue"
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
            value={event.venue}
          />
          <button type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.props.onCancel}>
            Cancel
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default EventFort
```

The newEvent is definitely a reference to the state, so it is changing the state directly. The code below proof that:

```
onInputChange = event => {
  const newEvent = this.state.event
  newEvent[evt.target.name] = event.target.value
  console.log(this.state.event) ​// => this.state.event {title: "a", venue: ""}
}
```

Ok now that is prove that the state is directly being mutated by the console log, my first instinct was to make a copy of state using spread operator.

```
onInputChange = event => {
  const newEvent = [...this.state.event] 
  newEvent[event.target.name] = event.target.value
  this.setState({
    event: newEvent
  })
}
```

However it works, as soon as I type in the input, I get the following error on the console:

```
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type
undefined to be uncontrolled.
Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or 
vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element
for the lifetime of the component. More info:
in input (at EventForm.jsx:43)
in form (at EventForm.jsx:34)
in div (at EventForm.jsx:28)
in EventForm (at EventDashboard.jsx:90)
in div (created by GridColumn)
in GridColumn (at EventDashboard.jsx:87)
in div (created by Grid)
in Grid (at EventDashboard.jsx:83)
in EventDashboard (at App.jsx:14)
in div (created by Container)
in Container (at App.jsx:13)
in div (at App.jsx:11)
in App
in AppContainer (at index.js:16)
```

So I'm sure there is better solution than the original code, that even it is working, it seems not the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't work directly on the state's object, when you create the new object just spread the state in and override the values.
You can use the [computed keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to make it generic:

```
  onInputChange = ({target}) => {
    const { event } = this.state;
    const newEvent = {
      ...event,
      [target.name]: target.value
    }
    this.setState({
      event: newEvent
    })
  }
```

Running example:

```js
class EventForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    event: {
      title: "",
      venue: ""
    }
  };

  onFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //..
  };

  onInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { event } = this.state;
    const newEvent = {
      ...event,
      [target.name]: target.value
    };
    this.setState({
      event: newEvent
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { event } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          Title: {this.state.event.title}
          <br />
          Venue: {this.state.event.venue}
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <label>Event Title</label>
          <input
            placeholder="title"
            name="title"
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
            value={event.title}
          />
          <label>Venue</label>
          <input
            name="venue"
            placeholder="Event Venue"
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
            value={event.venue}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.props.onCancel}>
            Cancel
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<EventForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot.